# How do you save edited csv file in a subfolder

Tags: python, pandas, csv, path

I have the following code in which I open all csv's from a file, I edit them and then save all of them as csv-1-edited.csv, csv-2-edited.csv etc.

I am trying to save these -edited.csv files into a separate subfolder.
I have tried different methods but none works.

Anyone has any idea?

Code:

```
    csv_folder = Path('folder-path')    
for file in csv_folder.glob('*.csv'): #Create iteratable & iterate on it.
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
[my code to edit the file]
    new_file_name = file.parent.joinpath(f"{file.stem}-edited.csv")
    df.to_csv(new_file_name, index=None, encoding='utf-8-sig', decimal=',')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best practice is to use `os.path.join()` since it joins two or more strings into a path according to your OS folder separator character (Windows '\' or Mac/Linux '/')

```py
import os
new_file_name = os.path.join(csv_folder, "new_sub_folder", f"{file.stem}-edited.csv")
```

Would output `<csv_folder>/new_sub_folder/<file.stem>-edited.csv` if ypu are using Mac/Linux

Comment: You guys rock! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Simply define the path to your subfolder

```
newpath = 'mysubfolder'
df.to_csv(newpath + '/' + filename , index=None, encoding='utf-8-sig', decimal=',')
```

and insert it in your code.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for the reply. I have tried this version and the error is: "can only concatenate str (not "WindowsPath") to str"

Answer (score 0):

After you've created the subfolder, add the folder name like this:

```
new_file_name = file.parent.joinpath(f"{folder_name}/{file.stem}-edited.csv")
```